# Hidden Markov model - Time Granularity

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model, sensitivity-analysis

Is Hidden Markov model sensitive on time granularity?

I mean if I train HMM parameters on dataset which time granularity is 1 minute. May I use the transition matrix and emissions distributions for data with time granularity 1 hour?

I would appreciate any literature source about this.

Comment: You can read about Variable Duration HMMs also called non-stationary HMMs. Here are two references on the topic:
- P. M. Djuric, J.-H. Chun, An MCMC sampling approach to estimation of non-stationary hidden Markov models, IEEE Trans. Signal Process. 50 (5) (2002) pp. 1113–1123.
- L. R. Rabiner, A tutorial on hidden Markov models and selected applications in speech recognition, Proc. IEEE 77 (2) (1989) pp. 257–286.
These papers provide more references on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the scale of your test data, either with a method as simple as replicating your data or a more complex one such as dynamic time warping.
This is similar to the way you magnify an image, where you need to interpolate values between pixels by simple replication or more complex methods.

Comment: I don't think this would work. Replicating data or filling holes by whatever method will lead the HMM to stay longer (for more time steps) in each hidden state. The HMM trained with artificially-filled data would obviously have a different transition matrix.

Comment: @Eskapp You expect similar signals to lead to similar HMMs. Am I right?

Comment: Not if they are sampled differently. The emissions may be the same, not the transition matrix.

Comment: HMM, like many other machine learning tools, is supposed to generalize beyond the training data and work well on similar (but not exactly same) data. So, IMHO, If HMM were so sensitive it would be of little use.

Comment: Keeping it short, some food for thought:
I have an HMM with 2 states which are associated with probability mass functions [p(A), p(B)] for two events A and B.
Now my data sampled every 5sec is A-B-A-B-A-B.
Filling my data for having a value every 1s would give: AAAAABBBBBAAAAABBBBBAAAAABBBBB
With both sampling, data will lead to an HMM with mass functions [p(A), p(B)] = [0 1] for the first state and [p(A), p(B)] = [1 0] for the second.
However, it seems clear to me that the transition matrices will not be the same if I train my HMM with the first sampling or the second one.

Comment: @Eskapp That is what I'm saying too, I don't expect the 2 models of yours to be similar, and that's why I'm suggesting that the signal be rescaled.

Comment: I think your answer is confusing then, maybe edit it and rephrase it ;) The question being: "May I use the (same) transition matrix [...] for data with time granularity 1 hour", the way I understand your answer is: Yes, to the condition you rescale your test data by replicating your samples for instance. However replicating the data and using the same transition matrix will clearly not work as we just said in the above comments...

Comment: 1) Interpolating the data will distort its dynamics and is not recommended 2) Generating more test data is nonsensical (what do you think you're testing?) 3) The solution is as simple as either thinning the training data and fitting directly on hourly data, OR computing the derived hourly transition matrix from the fitted 1 minute one, which is trivial due to the structure of HMM.